# Dual-boot Windows 10 / Debian 8 with UEFI/GPT

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, uefi, gpt

I am a user of a Dell Inspiron 15-3552 Windows10 pro 64bit.

I downloaded Debian 8.8-amd64-DVD-2.iso Linux distribution.

I used WinRAR to obtain Debian Os files, format the 32GB USB stick with Rufus to NTFS file system, GPT partition scheme for UEFI/EFI, cluster size default, create a bootable disk using UEFI:NTFS and included list of USB hard drives.

I copied the files to the USB stroke F12 found the USB device of the list but the error message was there was no boot.

Please tell me how to go about it. I just want to have windows and Linux distribution in the same machine (dual-boot).

I have even gone further to use VMWare Workstation Pro to no avail

Comment: Can you boot your machine into the EFI firmware (BIOS) and check if boot security is enabled?  Also, why did you unpack the ISO you downloaded?  Rufus just needs an ISO to make a bootable USB (check under usage here -> https://rufus.akeo.ie/)

Comment: @sgtbeano - Do you happen to mean Secure Boot?

Comment: Aye, that's the one :)

Comment: Yeah I tried to boot in UEFI/EFI boot mode secure boot off but I experienced the same problem. I have a copy of the packed ISO  so do you mean to copy it to the bootable disk the way it is?

Comment: I've tried the procedures that you'd given me but its still not booting... Kindly assist

Comment: Why are you using `Debian 8.8-amd64-DVD-2.iso`? AFAIK, this is a __supplementary__ installation media, and only `debian-8.8.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso` is bootable. If you want to install Debian, you should use `debian-8.8.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso`, NOT `debian-8.8.0-amd64-DVD-2.iso`.

Answer (score 0):

The path you used to create your boot medium is quite convoluted and strange. (Using NTFS for a Linux installation disk *might* work, but is strange at best, and I'd be surprised if it was a supported method.) Most Linux installation `.iso` files can be copied to a USB flash drive and made bootable with a command like this in Linux:

```
dd if=file.iso of=/dev/sdc
```

You'd need to type this command as `root` or by using `sudo`. If you don't have access to a computer that's already running Linux (or something similar), you can use [WinDD](https://sourceforge.net/projects/windd/). This example turns the USB flash drive accessible as `/dev/sdc` into a bootable image built from `file.iso`. This works because most Linux distributions create `.iso` images in a sort of Frankenstein's Monster format -- they can be read properly as ISO-9660 when written to optical discs *or* as FAT (IIRC) when written to USB flash drives. They can be booted in either BIOS or EFI mode when written to either medium, too.

In some cases this doesn't work, either because the distribution maintainers don't use this type of format or because of quirks with a particular computer. In this case, you can use a specialized Windows tool such as [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) (which of course you're using) or [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). You should not typically extract the files from the `.iso` files when using such programs; instead, feed them the original `.iso` file and point them to a USB drive that's been prepared in whatever way the instructions specify -- normally as one big FAT partition. Note that some such tools, like Pen Drive Linux (aka YUMI) do not create EFI-bootable media. If Rufus doesn't work for you, try using UNetbootin instead; or fiddle with the Rufus settings. (Rufus provides more settings than most such tools.)

Some people (particularly Mac users) have problems booting from USB flash drives. In these cases, burning the `.iso` file to a CD-R or recordable DVD often works better, if the target computer has an optical drive. This might be worth trying if you're having problems, even if you need to borrow an external optical drive.

If you continue to have problems, please post the *exact* error message you're seeing. If necessary, take a digital photo and post it here for us to see the *complete* error message.